Why is תָּם, which is usually translated 'whole' or 'blameless', translated as 'mild' or 'plain' when used of Jacob in Genesis 25:27?
A similar question was asked 8 years ago, here but there was only one attempt at an answer, and I'm wondering if there's more that can be added.
My question is, why is the Hebrew word תָּם, tām, translated in such an atypical way in Genesis 25:27?

27 So the boys grew. And Esau was a skillful hunter, a man of the field; but Jacob was a mild man, dwelling in tents. NKJV

My understanding is that the word means "complete" and is often translated "whole" or "without blemish" in regards to animal sacrifices, and "blameless" or "with integrity" in regards to people.
So, why in this instance, is it not translated as "blameless" or "with integrity" in regards to Jacob? Various translations translate it as "mild", "quiet", or (in the case of the KJV) "plain".
I can understand that it could have something to do with the context. Because in this same verse we have Esau referred to as a skillful hunter, and man of the field; this would suggest that the brothers are being described for their talents or personality, as opposed to their virtues or lack thereof. Still, I don't understand how you can get from "complete" to "mild" or "quiet".
Another reason why it not be translated "blameless" is that we know that Jacob doesn't seem to fit the description of a blameless man in that we learn in ensuing verses that he is prone to using dishonesty and subterfuge.
However the same word is used of David's integrity of heart, in Psalm 78:72, and he also was not above using subterfuge if the occasion called for it i.e. feigning madness before Abimelech.

Up-voted +1, but the question is being hindered by wrongful judgment against Jacob and David in regard to practical responses (Jacob''s response, supported by faithful Rebekah, to the unspiritual state of a previous generation - Isaac ; and David's expedience in preserving his life in the face of certain death).

Does this answer your question? Is Jacob depicted as "a quiet man" in Genesis 25:27?

If you do not believe that previous question answered adequately, then start a bounty to draw more attention to the previous question.

Yes @Dottard, you'll see that I linked that article in my post. It's got some interesting information there, but is essentially saying that tām can mean "peaceful", though I don't follow the reasoning, or am not sure that any reasoning is provided.

@NigelJ, I'm sorry if it seems like I was making a wrongful judgment against Jacob and David. I assumed it was generally accepted that Jacob was not above getting his way through underhanded means, just as his name means "supplanter". Hence him getting a taste of his own medicine in the way his uncle Laban treated him. Nonetheless, I understand that he was a man with spiritual instincts and inclinations and that his intentions were good.

I suggest you examine the three meanings of this word here >>  https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8535.htm

The key is the word "but" which indicates an opposite condition or state.  It is the contrast with his brother Esau that the usage of "tam" becomes associated more with a sense of completeness rather than seeking adventure, mild mannered rather than outgoing or cunning, quiet rather than bold, plain in the old sense of harmless or simple.  Whereas Esau was a skilled hunter who preferred the outdoors, Jacob was a herdsman, or shepherd.
Comment from Jameison-Fausset-Brown at Gen. 25:27 -

the boys grew—from the first, opposite to each other in character, manners, and habits. (Source: Biblehub)

The Pulpit Commentary here offers:

the antithesis of Esau - dwelling in tents - i.e. loving to stay at home, as opposed to Esau, who loved to wander afield; preferring a quiet, peaceable, domestic, and pious manner of existence to a life of "excitement, adventure, and danger," such as captivated Esau.  (Ibid)

And, Ellicott offers:

Esau became a skilful hunter, a “man of the field”: not a husbandman, but one who roamed over the open uncultivated wilderness (see Genesis 4:8) in search of game; but “Jacob was a plain man.” This is a most inadequate rendering of a word translated perfect in Job 1:1; Job 1:8; Psalm 37:37, &c, though this rendering is as much too strong as that in this verse is too weak. On Genesis 6:9, we have shown that the word conveys no idea of perfection or blamelessness, but only of general integrity. Both the word there and in Genesis 17:1, and the slightly different form of it used here, should in all places be translated upright.  (Ibid)

The context of the scripture at Gen. 25:27 rules, and the word "tam" provides the better sense there of sound or wholesome according to Brown-Driver-Briggs (Biblehub.

Thank you @Gina, this is a great answer. It makes sense that the conjunction "but" would be the clincher (I'm assuming that 'but' is in the Hebrew?). As I'd suspected, it's the description of Esau beforehand that gives some context for the use of "tam" to describe Jacob.
Regarding your quotes, though, it does seem like Ellicott is unconvinced that "plain" (and presumably other English translations) is an adequate translation of a word that is normally translated as "upright".

Yes, Ellicott is not one of my favorite commentaries.  I often disagree with his conclusions.  But, I included it as a point of  view that some might appreciate.  The use of any word in the scriptures always has to rely upon the context to determine the best definition of the word.
